# sed replacing first occurence of characters in each line of file only if they are first 2 characters

Tags: linux, string, file, sed, character

Is it possible using sed to replace the first occurrence of a character or substring in line of file only if it is the first 2 characters in the line?

For example we have this text file:

```
15 hello
15 h15llo
1 hello
1 h15loo
```

Using the following command: `sed -i 's/15/0/' file.txt`

Will give this output

```
0 hello
0 h15llo
1 hello
1 h0loo
```

What I am trying to avoid is it considering the characters past the first 2.
Is this possible?

Desired output:

```
0 hello
0 h15llo
1 hello
1 h15loo
```

Comment: sed -i 's/^15/0/' file.txt

Comment: When you show the current output, with your problem, `1 h15loo` is wrong. It will be `1 h0loo `

Comment: If a line existed like `153 foo` should it become `3 foo` or not change or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/^15 /0 /' file.txt
sed -i 's/^15\([[:space:]]\)/0\1/' file.txt
sed -i 's/^15\(\s\)/0\1/' file.txt
```

Here, the `^` matches the start of string position, 15 matches the `15` substring and then a space matches a space.

The second and third solutions are the same, instead of a literal space, they capture a whitespace char into Group 1 and the group value is put back into the result using the `\1` placeholder.